# How can we scan infected user uploaded files before moving to the right folder [Ubuntu+Apache+PHP+Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

How can we scan the files uploaded by the user from the application?

In our case when the user uploads the file from the application it goes to the /tmp directory and from the /tmp directory it goes to the S3 bucket. 
Server: Ubuntu + PHP5.6 + Laravel

How to restrict the infected file in the very first step when the user uploads the file and it goes to the /tmp?

Though I have tried to implement ClamAV security but it's not working on the ubuntu with PHP5.6 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please download the latest `php-clamav` tarball from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/php-clamav).
- Install `php5-dev`, `clamav` if you haven't already with `sudo apt-get`
- Extract the tarball, `cd` into the php-clamav-xxxx directory, and
  follow these steps to install the php-clamav module (adapted from
  `INSTALL`):

```
    phpize
    ./configure --with-clamav
    make
    cp modules/clamav.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
    (restart Apache)
    service httpd restart
```

Answer found in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166280/how-do-i-install-the-clamav-extension-for-php-5)